# Counterexample for: If P(A) + P(B) + P(C) = 1, then A,B,C are mutually exclusive

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-explanation, examples-counterexamples

[image: counterexample]

I understand the counterexample in terms of the algebra, but it is very unintuitive for me, for the following reason:

If A,B,C are not mutually exclusive, atleast 2 of the events overlap in the venn diagram. That means that for example: if I add $P(A) + P(B)$, I add $P(A \cap B)$ twice  which would give me 1 = $P(A) + P(B) - P(AB)$ which is the inclusion-exclusion principle. Obviously this is a contradiction that would prove the statement in the exercise correct because $P(A \cup B) = P(A)+P(B)$ only if A and B are mutually exclusive.

Am I misunderstanding the + operator?

Comment: Mutual exclusion applies for two items. You mean to say pairwise disjoint, perhaps?

Comment: I am uncertain of what you mean. Why only 2 terms? I thought mutual exclusive means that none of the probabilities can occur at the same time. Meaning they dont overlap in the Venn Diagram.

Comment: If the three events are not pairwise disjoint, then at least two of them overlap in the Venn diagram sense.

Comment: According to my book: A set of events
{E1, E2, . . .} is called mutually exclusive if the joint occurrence of any two
of them is impossible, that is, if ∀i 6= j, EiEj = ∅. Thus {E1, E2, . . .} is
mutually exclusive if and only if every pair of them is mutually exclusive.

Comment: That means none of them overlap in the Venn Diagram sense. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: I think I am mixing up union and adding. if the union of A,B,C = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) = 1 , then they would have to be mutual exclusive.

Comment: Yes, in the event of pairwise disjoint events, no two events overlap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean you mean to say the following.

> It is false that $P(A)+P(B)+P(C) = 1$ implies the events $A,B,C$ are pairwise disjoint.

And indeed it is, as the example shows.

The claim

> $P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$ only if $A\cap B=\emptyset$

is false. We can only conclude $P(A\cap B) = 0$.

---

I made a false claim in the comments saying that for finite sample space $P(A\cap B) = 0$ implies $A\cap B = \emptyset$. This is true if every singleton event has positive probability. A uniform distribution, for example, like the one with the dice.

Comment: Yes that was the claim I was making. But I get it now. Just because two sets overlap doesnt mean that the intersection has probability > 0. And if the probability of the intersection is 0, we don't have to subtract. You nailed it. Thank you.

Comment: Isnt the sample space in the counterexample finite?

Comment: Thank you! Just a general question. Why do people downvote questions like this? I know you didnt, but somebody else did.

Comment: @swisstackle Might be because of your liberal use of irrelevant tags (this has nothing to do with set theory, for instance - elementary set theory might be permissible). I don't really know.

Comment: Oh okay. Ill change that. Thank you.